# Extract specific words from string

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Column_A
1. A lot of text inhere, but I want all words that have a comma in the middle. Like this: hello,world. A string can contain multiple relevant words, like hello,python and we have also many                         whit                spaces              in          the text   
2. What I want is to abstract,all words with that pattern. Not sure if it has an impact, but some parts of the strings containing "this signs". or "this,signs"                                     thanks  for helpingme                    greets!
```

Desired outcome:

```
hello,world
hello,python
abstract,all
"this,signs"
```

I tried to do this with this code:

```
df['B'] = df['Column_A'].str.findall(r',').str.join(' ').str.strip()
```

But that is giving me not the desired outcome.

Comment: Try `"?[\w]+,[\w]+"?`

Comment: `df['B'] = df['Column_A'].str.findall(r'("[a-z]+,[a-z]+"|[a-z]+,[a-z]+)')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the specific format of the expected output, it seems that you could use:

```
from itertools import chain

l = chain.from_iterable(df.Column_a.str.findall(r'\w+,\w+').values.tolist())
pd.Dataframe(l, columns=['Column_A'])

      Column_A
0   hello,world
1  hello,python
2  abstract,all
3    this,signs
```

Comment: Not sure but `"this,signs"` is not `this,signs`. Maybe the quotes are necessary.

Comment: In such case `print(pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df.Column_a.str.findall(r'\W{1}\w+,\w+\W{1}').values.tolist())))` could work for instance @jan Not sure though if this expects to other special characters though or just `"`..? Thats why I went with this simpler approach